# C# group multiple structs and pass to function parameter?

Tags: c#

I use a namespace with many structs inside, I have a method that I want to call, currently I am using "object" type as parameter to pass all my structs from the namespace (I am aware that I could make parent class to child class and use parent type as a filter, but I am interested into possibility of structs).

Is there a way to limit the passed Objects to only types of my namespace?

Thanks for any advice (I am a beginner).

Comment: You are not supposed to use namespaces to control visibility though. How about limiting the passed objects to only types in a certain assembly? You can do this by making the method internal, and making it accept an internal interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to limit by namespace, however you can limit the parameter type if you use generics and constraint them by interface. For example:

```
public interface MyInterface {}

public struct MyStruct : MyInterface {}

public struct MyOtherStruct: MyInterface {}

public class MyClass
{
   public void MyMethod<T>(T myParameter) where T: MyInterface
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Additional on this, i want to not get rid of the namespace, just to have "Context" when writing code. Whenever i use GetType() from an object, it always returns "Namespace.Struct". So if i do this: "Namespace.Struct == Struct" will this create Problems in future?

Comment: @dabcpp. What you are asking is not clear to me. Additionally I don't know what you are trying to achieve. I suggest you to ask a new question, describing your problem, Don't ask how to implement the solution you have thought, because it looks like a XY problem  to me.